# Apache send all post data nice and clear to Graylog

Tags: apache, logging, mod-security, graylog

what I need to achieve is, having apache requests be logged in my graylog.
I already accomplished this task, and here is part of my apache vhost which is related to this task :

```
LogFormat "{ \"version\": \"1.1\", \"host\": \"%V\", \"short_message\": \"%r\", \"timestamp\": %{%s}t, \"level\": 6, \"_user_agent\": \"%{User-Agent}i\", \"_source_ip\": \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\", \"_duration_usec\": %D, \"_duration_sec\": %T, \"_request_size_byte\": %O, \"_http_status_orig\": %s, \"_http_status\": %>s, \"_http_request_path\": \"%U\", \"_http_request\": \"%U%q\", \"_http_method\": \"%m\", \"_http_referer\": \"%{Referer}i\", \"_from_apache\": \"true\" }" graylog_access
CustomLog "|/bin/nc -u 192.168.50.21 12201" graylog_access
```

but I realized I don't have post request body in my log.
I searched through internet and I came up with installing apache mod_security
and sending it's log to my graylog
and here is my modsecurity config:

```
SecRuleEngine Off

SecRequestBodyAccess On

SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "(?:text|application)/xml" \
     "id:'200000',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"

SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "application/json" \
     "id:'200001',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=JSON"

SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 131072

SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072

SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject

SecRule REQBODY_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200002', phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to parse request body.',logdata:'%{reqbody_error_msg}',severity:2"

SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200003',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400, \
msg:'Multipart request body failed strict validation: \
PE %{REQBODY_PROCESSOR_ERROR}, \
BQ %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_QUOTED}, \
BW %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_WHITESPACE}, \
DB %{MULTIPART_DATA_BEFORE}, \
DA %{MULTIPART_DATA_AFTER}, \
HF %{MULTIPART_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
LF %{MULTIPART_LF_LINE}, \
SM %{MULTIPART_MISSING_SEMICOLON}, \
IQ %{MULTIPART_INVALID_QUOTING}, \
IP %{MULTIPART_INVALID_PART}, \
IH %{MULTIPART_INVALID_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
FL %{MULTIPART_FILE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED}'"

SecRule MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200004',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,msg:'Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary.'"

SecPcreMatchLimit 100000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 100000

SecRule TX:/^MSC_/ "!@streq 0" \
        "id:'200005',phase:2,t:none,deny,msg:'ModSecurity internal error flagged: %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}'"

SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "POST" "id:1000,phase:2,ctl:auditEngine=On,nolog,pass"

SecResponseBodyAccess On

SecResponseBodyMimeType text/plain text/html text/xml

SecResponseBodyLimit 524288

SecResponseBodyLimitAction ProcessPartial


SecTmpDir /tmp/

SecDataDir /tmp/



SecAuditEngine On
SecAuditLogRelevantStatus "^(?:5|4(?!04))"

SecAuditLogParts ABDEFHIJZ

SecAuditLogType Serial
# SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
SecAuditLog "|/bin/nc -u 192.168.50.21 12201"

SecArgumentSeparator &

SecCookieFormat 0

SecUnicodeMapFile unicode.mapping 20127
SecStatusEngine On
```

please help me with finishing this task.

and you can find more complete apache vhost here.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
#    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    LogFormat "{ \"version\": \"1.1\", \"host\": \"%V\", \"short_message\": \"%r\", \"timestamp\": %{%s}t, \"level\": 6, \"_user_agent\": \"%{User-Agent}i\", \"_source_ip\": \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\", \"_duration_usec\": %D, \"_duration_sec\": %T, \"_request_size_byte\": %O, \"_http_status_orig\": %s, \"_http_status\": %>s, \"_http_request_path\": \"%U\", \"_http_request\": \"%U%q\", \"_http_method\": \"%m\", \"_http_referer\": \"%{Referer}i\", \"_from_apache\": \"true\" }" graylog_access
    CustomLog "|/bin/nc -u 192.168.50.21 12201" graylog_access

    <Directory /var/www>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/public>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```